Why does FFmpeg encoding stall on Ubuntu with DVD video file?
I've encountered a challenging issue while using FFmpeg on Ubuntu to encode a DVD video file contained in a .bin format. Despite various attempts (also employing vlc or bounting converted .iso), including adjusting command complexity, the process stalls immediately, showing no progress beyond the first frame.
The simplified command used was:
ffmpeg -i image.bin output.mp4

This resulted in audio-only output, with VLC displaying a black screen or sometimes just thumbnails.
To closely adhere to the video's specifications (see below), I also tried a more detailed command without success:
ffmpeg -i image.bin -target pal-dvd -aspect 4:3 -b:v 777k \
  -minrate 300k -maxrate 2530k -bufsize 1835k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 128k \
  -y output.mpg

This command stalls immediately after initiation, displaying:
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:01:14.27 bitrate=   0.0kbits
frame=    1 fps=1.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:01:35.69 bitrate=   0.0kbits
frame=    1 fps=0.7 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:01:50.95 bitrate=   0.0kbits
frame=    1 fps=0.5 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:02:04.29 bitrate=   0.0kbits
frame=    1 fps=0.4 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:02:16.55 bitrate=   0.0kbits
...
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:34:28.15 bitrate=   0.0kbits

Or was I too impatient?
The context is an attempt to process video files from a video tape to DVD or SVCD conversion project that apparently was done on Windows, with a directory structure as follows:
.
├── AVISYNTH.INI
├── CD_Image_File_CD1.bin
├── CD_Image_File_CD1.cue
├── dvd2svcd_log.txt
└── ___movie.ini

Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
FFmpeg Version: 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
Video File Characteristics I was able to read out:
GENERAL INFO
- Source:       DVD (PAL)
- Movie Offset:     2 sec
- CD Overlap seconds:   Yes, 2 sec
- Startup delays:   Video: 180 ms Audio 1: 180 msAudio 2: 180 ms
- Video format:     PAL
- Length:       01:59:43
- CD Images:        1
   
VIDEO INFO:
- Encoder:      Cinema Craft Encoder 2.50.1.0
- Encoding mode:    Multipass VBR
- Passes:       2
- Max. bitrate:     2530
- Avg. bitrate:     777
- Min. bitrate:     300
- Bias: 20
- Image Quality Prio:   17
- Antinoise filter: No
- Linear quant. scale:  Yes
- Zigzag scan order:    Yes
- Upper field first:    No
- Progressive frames:   Yes
- iDCT Algorithm:   32-bit SSE MMX
- Deinterlace:      None
- Pulldown:     No
- Width:        480
- Height:       576
- Matrix:
            Intra:
             8 16 19 22 26 27 29 34 
            16 16 22 24 27 29 34 37 
            19 22 26 27 29 34 34 38 
            22 22 26 27 29 34 37 40 
            22 26 27 29 32 35 40 48 
            26 27 29 32 35 40 48 58 
            26 27 29 34 38 46 56 69 
            27 29 35 38 46 56 69 83 
            Non-Intra:
            16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
            17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 
            18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 
            19 20 21 22 23 24 26 27 
            20 21 22 23 25 26 27 28 
            21 22 23 24 26 27 28 30 
            22 23 24 26 27 28 30 31 
            23 24 25 27 28 30 31 33 

AVISYNTH SCRIPT:
LoadPlugin("C:\PROGRA~1\DVD2SVCD\AVISYN~1.5PL\Mpeg2dec\MPEG2D~1.DLL")
mpeg2source("D:\dvd2svcd\DVD2AV~1.D2V")
BicubicResize(480,576,0.0,0.6)
Import("D:\dvd2svcd\ResampleAudio.avs")
ResampleAudio(44100)
ConvertToYUY2()


AUDIO INFO:
- Audiostreams:     1
- Audio 1 Language: 
- Audio 1 Bitrate:  128
- Audio 1 Sample freq:  44100
- Audio 1 Mode:     Stereo
- Audio 1 Besweet:  "C:\Programme\DVD2SVCD\BeSweet\BeSweet.exe" -core( -input "D:\dvd2svcd\Extracted_audio_1.ac3" -output "D:\dvd2svcd\Encoded_audio_1.mp2" -logfile "D:\dvd2svcd\Encoded_audio_1.log" ) -azid( -L -3db -l 0db -c normal -s surround -g max ) -ota( -d -80 ) -shibatch( --rate 44100 ) -2lame( -e -b 128 -m s )

SUBTITLE INFO:
- Subtitlestreams:  0
- Type:         
- Sub. 1 Language:  
- Sub. 2 Language:  
- Sub. 3 Language:  
- Sub. 4 Language:  

AUTHORING INFO:
- CD Image program: VCDXBuild
- Entrysvd:     No

Given the specifics above, I'm reaching out for insights on why FFmpeg stalls and how to resolve this to get my video, especially considering the unique characteristics of the video file and the initially successful audio extraction. Any advice on alternative approaches or command adjustments that could potentially bypass this stalling issue would be immensely appreciated.

DVDs are a complex format with multiple streams and titles and whatnot. But the log file suggests this is not what you have. Instead, it would be a Super Video CD, something else entirely.

@DanielB Thanks for your comment. You're right, somewhere the character string "svcd" actually jumped out at me! Any suggestions?

The only way I see would be to “rip” the SVCD first, like in the days of old. Unfortunately, I’m not sure how you would do that on Linux. The format is very much unlike DVDs or regular data CDs, it is closer to audio CDs. vcdxrip is mentioned as a possible tool, as is KDE’s k3b, but I cannot verify this. Maybe check this related answer on Unix SE.

Handbrake should be able to rip it.
